# Recommendations on TeamFoundation Server 2010 Installation and Configuration Consulting

Tags: tfs

We recently switched from a local, simple single machine TF 2008 server to an IT managed TF 2010 uber-server setup in a centralized (but offsite) location.  Now, all hell is breaking loose from the server being down a *lot* to the Team Build service causing failed builds.  I'm not entirely sure if this is an indictment on the quality of TFS 2010 or the lack of experience/competence our IT department has with setting up a multi-tier, clustered mongo TF server.

What are some good consulting companies we could pull in to look at our TFS 2010 setup and let us know what's messed up about it?  I would prefer to hear from folks that have first hand experience with these consultants but second hand "word of mouth" would also be OK.

The unfortunate effect here is that folks are starting to talk about TFS as if it were  not much better than Visual Source Safe in terms of reliability!  That's a bummer because TFS 2008 worked extremely well for us when we managed on our simple server setup.  And some folks, already somewhat anti-Microsoft, are chomping at the bit to move to GIT.  You know, the grass always being greener on the other side and all.  :-)

I have to believe, based on Microsoft's rather large internal usage, that TFS 2010 should be performing a lot better than it is for us.

Comment: "from the server being down a lot to the Team Build service causing failed builds" - these both sound like PEBKACs. Are you sure they're relevant?

Comment: Well there is no end user involved with automated nightly build failures.  I do suspect that the IT folks that set up the server aren't particular experienced in this area.  Hence the desire to bring someone in to check out how they have the servers configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A great place to start is the Microsoft partners that have achieved the Application Lifecycle Management (ALM) competency.

Here is the list of them on Microsoft Pinpoint: http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/companies/search?fs=154